# Regular Expressions modification

Tags: regex

I am working on `REGEX` and trying to match below criteria:

- It should match `a-z, A-Z, 0-9`
- ~`!@#$^*_=[]/|\,.?: -`   allowed
- `<>{}"'%;()&+`   not allowed

and in the process I have come up with below regex, but in some cases, it fails.

```
/^(?=[a-zA-Z0-9~!@#$^*_=[\/]|\\,.?: -]*$)(?!.*[<>{}"'%;()&+])/
```

Would appreciate if any expert can validate and modify the same if required.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: In which language are you using this regex? PHP, JS, ASP?

Comment: In which cases does it fail?

Comment: when you are using ^ this symbol or special char to find use backslash \ and for  <>{}"'%;()&+ this use like this     ' [^<>\{\}"'%;\(\)&+] ' .

Comment: @Bohemian when i press / or \

Answer (score 2):

If you know what's allowed, you don't need to list what's *not* allowed. Just express it as a character class of the allowed chars:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9~!@#$^*_=[\/]|\\,.?: -]*$/
```

Answer (score 1):

To me, it looks like you need something like:

```
if (/^[\w~!@#$^*=[\]\/|\\,.?: -]$/.test(subject)) {
    // Successful match
} else {
    // Match attempt failed
}
```

1. In JavaScript the `\w` will match any ASCII letter, digit or underscore (more compact).
2. Two characters to which you need to pay attention are the `]` and `\`, which both need to be escaped by a backslash.